# Remove Illegal Characters from SQL Server 2005 Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server 2005 and one of my field in house_no as nvarchar, which contains hindi, numeric and both combination values like -

```
* 1
* 2/1
* 31/1सी 
* 3 मैन्ट भवन 
* हट मैन्ट भवन 
* 12ूूू
* 14ु
* ैुौ
```

Now I want to delete all of the illegal characters like ू or ैुौ and many more from string and preserve the rest. I have used replace() function but it is not working on hindi characters. Please can anyone suggest another solution? My database is big - nearly 200GB and I have to replace all such characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try using N '' before the characters you are replacting.